# Finding specific IP address and echo results

Tags: batch-file

I have multiple IP address in IPv4. However using commands like

`ipconfig | findstr /R /C:"IPv4 Address"`

will show multiple results

I'm looking for a batch file to capture a specific IPv4 address which starts with

> 192

And will display the full IP address:

> 192.168.100.232

With the results I would like to split it into segments like

> A=192
>   B=168
>   C=100
>   D=232

So that I can `echo %A.%B.%C.%D`

which will display

> 192.168.100.232

As I need to do telnet with lots of devices with multiple address. Its annoying to keep searching for the IP address.

So my codes would have as a result as shown below:

> telnet %A.%B.%C.80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "match=10"

    set "ip="
    for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=. " %%a in ('
        route  print -4 %match%.* ^| find /v "..."
    ') do (
        if not defined ip if "%%a"=="%match%" set "ip=%%a.%%b.%%c.80"
    )

    if not defined ip (
        echo IP address not found
        goto :eof
    )

    echo %ip%
```

Comment: thank you. this is the answer that i needed. could you guide me which area to change if i need to change the 192 to 10. as after change the value 192 to 10. it shows some weird results.

Comment: @marcuschan, see updated answer. Changed values in code to variable to make it easier to change.

Comment: weird haha. it works great on my other pc. not on my own pc. seems to be taking the physical address off my PC.

Comment: @marcuschan, try the updated code. The `192` generates no problem, but `10` can match the adapter ID in the output of the `route` command. I've filtered the lines in the `interfaces` header.

Comment: yes it works great as well. and i understand why as well. also on my pc im running ssl client. no clients running on my other pc. so it still works great.! ! thats most important